# Center div inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have two divs

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {
    width: 45%; height: 500px;
    margin-right:2.5%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

#div2 {
    width: 45%; height: 300px;
    margin-right:2.5%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

Gives me this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9EGy.png

As you can see my second(small) div is at the buttom of the other, how can I 
center it verticaly.

I tried to put them in another div and use vertical-align:minddle

Comment: In your question you have a typo in the value `middle`. Is that in your actual code? Also if you use `span` rather than `div` you get an inline element so that vertical aligning works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `vertical-align: middle` to both divs and the blue one will appear vertically centered. See here: http://codepen.io/alexbaulch/pen/LVVqzG

Answer (score 1):

In order to use vertical-align: middle; you need to set display: inline or display: inline-block, these two go together.

```css
#div1 {
    width: 45%; height: 500px;
    margin-right:2.5%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#div2 {
    width: 45%; height: 300px;
    margin-right:2.5%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```